# NGINX SSL / Routing

Tags: nginx, ssl, routing

This issue is an extension of the previous issue that I had, where I wanted to route an IP address to my SSL enabled hostname, which now works fine as intended however what I noticed is, on the chrome browser I can see the security padlock icon and it works great, but on Firefox and EDGE, it gives me security warnings.

Does the below code in the NGINX file needs some additional inputs?

**This is the original issue for reference** - Which got fixed with the below nginx config.

> I have my domain example.com, so when someone hits on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
> or example.com the request is automatically directed to
> https://example.com - which works fine. However, when I use IP address
> of the node app 1.2.3.4 it doesn't route to https://example.com which
> is SSL enabled. If I use the IP address, it shows me the same page but
> without the padlock icon.
>
> So how do I route a request to https://example.com when someone enters
> the IP address of node app?
>
> My Node JS APP is hosted on AWS EC2 instance, I have also installed
> ssl using certbot (LetsEncrpyt). This is my nginx file.

```
 events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
 
 
  index    index.html index.htm;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   logs/access.log  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts


# Settings for normal server listening on port 80
server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  listen       [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com 1.2.3.4;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  # location / {
  # }
  # Redirect non-https traffic to https

  if ($host = 1.2.3.4){
    return 301 https://www.example.com;
  }

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
server {
  listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com 1.2.3.4;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";

  if ($host = $server_addr){
    return 301 https://www.example.com;
  }


  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
}
```

These are the screenshots from Firefox I have just covered up the domain name

[image]

```
After clicking on the Error code : SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN, this is what I get 

https://www.example.com/

Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server’s certificate.

HTTP Strict Transport Security: false
HTTP Public Key Pinning: false

Certificate chain:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFUTCCBDmgAwIBAgISA152qQHyniTjMg0Mtz+8CCp1MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
MEoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MSMwIQYDVQQD    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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEkjCCA3qgAwIBAgIQCgFBQgAAAVOFc2oLheynCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT
DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTE2MDMxNzE2NDA0NloXDTIxMDMxNzE2NDA0Nlow
SjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUxldCdzIEVuY3J5cHQxIzAhBgNVBAMT
GkxldCdzIEVuY3J5cHQgQXV0aG9yaXR5IFgzMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC
AQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnNMM8FrlLke3cl03g7NoYzDq1zUmGSXhvb418XCSL7e4S0EF
q6meNQhY7LEqxGiHC6PjdeTm86dicbp5gWAf15Gan/PQeGdxyGkOlZHP/uaZ6WA8    
CCsGAQUFBzABhiZodHRwOi8vaXNyZy50cnVzdGlkLm9jc3AuaWRlbnRydXN0LmNv
bTA7BggrBgEFBQcwAoYvaHR0cDovL2FwcHMuaWRlbnRydXN0LmNvbS9yb290cy9k
c3Ryb290Y2F4My5wN2MwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUxKexpHsscfrb4UuQdf/EFWCFiRAw
VAYDVR0gBE0wSzAIBgZngQwBAgEwPwYLKwYBBAGC3xMBAQEwMDAuBggrBgEFBQcC
ARYiaHR0cDovL2Nwcy5yb290LXgxLmxldHNlbmNyeXB0Lm9yZzA8BgNVHR8ENTAz
MDGgL6AthitodHRwOi8vY3JsLmlkZW50cnVzdC5jb20vRFNUUk9PVENBWDNDUkwu
Y3JsMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSoSmpjBH3duubRObemRWXv86jsoTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
AAOCAQEA3TPXEfNjWDjdGBX7CVW+dla5cEilaUcne8IkCJLxWh9KEik3JHRRHGJo
uM2VcGfl96S8TihRzZvoroed6ti6WqEBmtzw3Wodatg+VyOeph4EYpr/1wXKtx8/
wApIvJSwtmVi4MFU5aMqrSDE6ea73Mj2tcMyo5jMd6jmeWUHK8so/joWUoHOUgwu
X4Po1QYz+3dszkDqMp4fklxBwXRsW10KXzPMTZ+sOPAveyxindmjkW8lGy+QsRlG
PfZ+G6Z6h7mjem0Y+iWlkYcV4PIWL1iwBi8saCbGS5jN2p8M+X+Q7UNKEkROb3N6
KOqkqm57TH2H3eDJAkSnh6/DNFu0Qg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

For the EDGE browser, it displays "Not Secure:https://1.2.3.4" with https being struck out.

But for chrome everything works correctly. no errors or warnings

Comment: Perhaps you could share those security warnings?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I have updated the post with screenshots and error data.

Comment: I think the explanation Firefox gave you is perfectly clear and understandable. What are you still confused about?

Comment: Chrome  shouldn't accept it if Edge or Firefox don't.  Perhaps you need to clear its cache.  The messages says that Nginx presents a certificate that does not belong to the domain you are visigin.  I paid a visit to https: // www.clxxxxxte.in and the certificate belongs to clxxxxxte.in, not www.clxxxxxte.in.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille    Since I am using the LetsEncrypt certificate, the free version. Is it because they don't support multidomain ? or what do you suggest that I can do to avoid this? - Thanks for your findings.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am pretty much new to SSL, NIGINX and in general infra setup, so some of those warnings may not ring a bell with me right away. :)

Comment: LetsEncrypt says they do support multiple domain and wildcard.  What do you have for www.xlxxxxxte.in ?

Comment: @Gerad H. Pille   I used this article to help me install certificates https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/serving-a-website-on-a-registered-domain-with-https-using-nginx-and-lets-encrypt-8d482e01a682  and then using this command to generate the certificate "sudo /usr/bin/certbot-auto --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com --debug"

Comment: The certificate only contains example.com, not www.example.com